# Cant find what is wrong

Tags: java, android

lets say i got 2 balls 1 names gball the other blueb.
what im basicly trying to do is everytime my gball center point(x,y)
is inside the blueb 
the blueb will change place to a random place
the problem is the blueb wont change place and the audio dosent work(MyAudio is the class that starts the audio).
this is my code ;

```
@Override
public void run() {
Random r = new Random();
int rX = r.nextInt(350  + 1);
int rY = r.nextInt(450  + 1);

while (isRunnning) {
  if(!ourHolder.getSurface().isValid())
    continue;

  Canvas canvas=ourHolder.lockCanvas();
  canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);

  if(x !=0 && y!=0){
    Bitmap test=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.raw.ball);
    canvas.drawBitmap(test, x-test.getWidth()/2, y-test.getHeight()/2, null);

    Bitmap blueb=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.raw.bball);
    canvas.drawBitmap(blueb, rX, rY, null);

    if(x-test.getWidth()/2 <=rX+40 && x-test.getWidth()/2 >=rX-40 && y-test.getHeight()/2 <=rY+40 &&   y-test.getHeight()/2 >=rY-40 ) {
      MediaPlayer mp1=MediaPlayer.create(GFXSurface.this, R.raw.im);
      MyAudio beep=new MyAudio(mp1);
      beep.getAudio().start();

      rX = r.nextInt(350  + 1);
      rY = r.nextInt(450  + 1);
      canvas.drawBitmap(blueb, rX, rY, null);
    }           
  }
```

notes: the gball center is in (x-test.getWidth()/2, y-test.getHeight()/2)
and the 40 is the blueb radius.

Comment: It would be much easier to check that condition (one ball inside another one) if you create a mathmatical vector using both center points and then get its length. If the length is smaller then the radius of `blueb`, then `gball` is inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

Your conditional for checking if the balls overlap needs work.  Look closely..

```
x-test.getWidth()/2 <=rX+40 && x-test.getWidth()/2 >=rX-40
```

The only way that conditional evaluates to true is if the center of 'test' is in the exact center of 'x'.  The center of 'x' cannot both be less than and greater than a value; so this is only true in the equals case.  I assume you have some physics system or user input moving the balls which means it will very rarely satisfy the exactly equals case but they will overlap a lot.

What you should do is get the radius of each ball, add them together, and check if the distance between the center of 'x' and the center of 'test' is less than the combined radii.  That will let you know if they overlap or not.

Comment: everytime i try to define variables like p for the distance it gives me a fatal error..

Answer (score 0):

Let's have a look the conditions one after another.

```
if(x-test.getWidth()/2 <=rX+40 && x-test.getWidth()/2 >=rX-40 && y-test.getHeight()/2 <=rY+40 &&   y-test.getHeight()/2 >=rY-40 )
```

For better understandig i suggest the use of variables. I think Tansir1 didn't notice that there is a minus into the second condition:

```
int gballCenterXCoordinate = x-test.getWidth()/2;
int gballCenterYCoordinate = y-test.getHeight()/2;
int bluebCenterXCoordinate = rX;
int bluebRightX = bluebCenterXCoordinate + 40;
int bluebLeftX = bluebCenterXCoordinate - 40;
int bluebCenterYCoordinate = rY;
int bluebTopY = bluebCenterYCoordinate + 40;
int bluebBottomY = bluebCenterYCoordinate - 40;
```

after this your condition looks like this:

```
if(gballCenterXCoordinate  <= bluebRightX &&  
  gballCenterXCoordinate  >= bluebLeftX && 
  gballCenterYCoordinate  <= bluebTopY &&   
  gballCenterYCoordinate  >= bluebBottomY )
```

This condition is true if gball enter the square with (bluebCenterX,bluebCenterY) as Center.

Did you try to debug wether the code into the if is reached?
Maybe your condition is true but the code into the if block doesn't work?

Hope this helps

Comment: You've got a typo in your line `int bluebBottomY = bluebCenterYCoordinate + 40;`